# Difficulties with JQuery Pagination

Tags: jquery, pagination

I'm a bit stuck and would appreciate some help.

I'm developing an ASP.Net MVC 5 web application. On one of the razor views I will return a list of strings and display them. The list will never contain anymore than 90 strings. For example

```
String 1
String 2
String 3
String ...
String 90
```

Rather than list all 90 strings to the user, I would like to offer a pagination option so that the user can view 30 strings at a time. I've googled quite a few JQuery pagination plugins, but they all seem a bit complicated.

Say I put the 90 strings into 3 DIVs (each DIV to containing 30 strings). Do I have to hide 2 DIVs whilst showing the other? Just really confused about the best approach here.

Any advice on guidance or a JQuery plugin would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: show us your attempt, not just mentioning what you thought about trying, try it

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: If you're paging on the client just for user convenience, then yes, simply load all into the page with some hidden.   From MVC razor, easiest way is to put each string in a separate div while hiding any divs with index > 30.  Then your jquery would get all the divs and splice them (there's quite a few answers already on SO that show this).

Comment: @depperm I sort of understand your response, I too don't like questions on stack being added without effort being portrayed by the person asking the question. In this case though, I am not asking you to look at my code, more my approach of how it might work, hence the question about hiding DIV tags. A simple yes or no answer is suffice here, not a condescending response.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks, that's all I needed to know.